# Wireless headset that works with PC and mobile phone

Tags: wireless, windows, mobile-phone, headset

I'm looking for a wireless headset that satisfies all of the following requirements and for the life of me, I can't seem to find anything that meets all my needs.

Requirements:

- Should be able to listen to both devices "at the same time" (e.g. listen to music coming from the PC and also hear the ring of an incoming phone call, or at least just need to pause the music and then hear/receive the phone call)
- When using the PC to make calls (e.g. Skype, Google Voice/Hangouts), the sound should be in (or close to) Studio quality (e.g. at least 2 channels, 24 bit, 48000 Hz)
- Should be able to mute the mic with a single touch or action (e.g. pulling up the mic) of a button on the headset
- Noise cancellation

Nice to have features:

- Use a single wireless technology (e.g. Bluetooth), but it's perfectly fine if it requires a dongle (RF)
- Surround sound and/or 7 channels
- Form factor similar to the [Motorola Buds](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00H0CV9TM) or the [Motorola S11](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B009M27MB2)
- Works with PlayStation 3 and/or 4, meaning, listen to the game audio, not just for voice chats
- Accept an incoming phone call by pressing a button on the headset

What I have tried (and why it didn't work):

- Motorola Buds: Uses just BT, but can't pair to two devices at the same time. To add insult to injury, when using Skype on PC, sound quality is reduced to mono, 8-bit, crappy phone quality and it creates two different audio playback devices, so music does sound good (high quality), but for calls/communication, you're forced to use the low quality audio playback device.
- Logitech G933 Artemis Spectrum: Does not use BT, so to listen to the mobile phone, you have to connect the phone to the headset's dongle, which in turn connects to the PC. I don't mind all those connections, the problem is that the dongle only "streams" audio out to the headset, but cannot provide (headset) mic input to the phone. The only way to fully connect the phone to the headset is by connecting the phone via AUX cable to the headset, which completely breaks the wireless requirement.

Comment: Do you have _any_ price limit?

Comment: $200, maybe $300 if the solution really hits all the high notes.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, bluetooth won't provide high quality sound *and* using the microphone by its standard. From my research I think the [SteelSeries Sibera 840](https://steelseries.com/gaming-headsets/siberia-840) might be a good match, it can be used with most consoles and PCs and includes bluetooth. The catch is it's no earbuds, but then again I doubt you could get proper surround sound from buds...

Comment: Thanks for the recommendation, seems like that would be as closed as it gets to what I want. I settled for the G933, but next time I'm on the market for headphones, I'll definitely give the Sibera 840 a try.